# Deploying Fiori Appl issue from local webide (Could not deploy application Error 500 server error)

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am unable to deploy fiori application from past few days from local webide .suddenly its showing 
Deploying component-preload.js 
(Could not deploy application Z_Application - Error 500 server error)
But if i tried to deploy from abap system using /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD then am able to deploy 
application. Could any one help me on these issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the connection between your local Web IDE instance and your SAP system is the cause of the issue if you’re able to zip up the files yourself and import into the system manually using the provided report.

Have you changed any configuration on your local machine since your last successful deployment? Firewall rules, software installs, windows updates etc?

Also, it’ll be worth checking the ICM trace to get more detailed error information. It may be that the SAP system is blocking the connection for some reason.

Equally has there been any changes to your SAP system recently - enhancements or service packs?